# Django class based views queryset model isn't defined

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am producing a web app in `Django` that stores and sorts courses. The issue I am having is that the query set is not recognizing the model. I have managed to pull all in a class based view and mess around with the data, however, when I try and do a query set it simply says that the model "Course" is not defined. I have imported the following model:

```
class Course(models.Model):

    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)

    title = models.CharField('Course Title',
    max_length=200,
    )

    first_line = models.CharField('Address Line: 1',
    max_length=200,
    )
    second_line = models.CharField('Address Line: 2',
    max_length=200,
    )
    third_line = models.CharField('Address Line: 3',
    max_length=200,
    )
    city = models.CharField('City',
    max_length=200,
    )
    post_code = models.CharField('Post Code',
    max_length=200,
    )
    course_description = models.TextField('Description')
    date = models.DateField('Date')

    start_time = models.TimeField('Starting time')
    finish_time = models.TimeField('Finishing time')
    duration = models.IntegerField('Number of hours')
    CPD = models.IntegerField('CPD points')
    link = models.CharField('Link', max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    gen_cat = models.ForeignKey(Gen_Categories)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Gen_Location)
    cost = models.FloatField('Cost')
```

And I have the following class-based view. The functions that are there like `date_screen()` were written in another file and imported, they work in my function based views. The issue is that it keeps saying that `Course` is not defined. If you can find anything else wrong with the class based view please give me a heads up. I can develop a class based view that pulls all data but any more nuance is a head spin at the moment.

```
class Courses_By_Location(ListView):
    template_name = 'courses/course_list.html'
    model = Course

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.Course = get_object_or_404(Course, name=self.args[0].order_by('date'))
        raw_courses = Course.objects.filter(location=self.location)
        courses = date_screen(raw_courses)
        categories = category_screen(courses)
       locations = location_screen(courses)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(searchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'locations': self.locations,
               'categories': self.categories,
               'courses': self.courses,
               'count': self.count,})
        return context
```

Comment: If you could post the working function based view, it's more likely I could find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have taken the other answer as he has completely rewritten the view and it works so well and is very clear. Again thank you for taking the time out to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but it looks like you're placing some things in inappropriate places.

```
# URLs
url(
    r'^local/(?P<location>[-\w]+)/$',
    views.Courses_By_Location.as_view(),
    name='by_location',
),

# Views
class Courses_By_Location(ListView):
    model = Course
    context_object_name = 'courses'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location = kwargs.get('location', 'DEFAULT-LOCATION')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # `date_screen` must return a QuerySet
        return date_screen(
            # assuming the `Gen_Location` model has a `name` field
            super().get_queryset().filter(location__name__iexact=self.location),
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['locations'] = location_screen(self.object_list)
        context['categories'] = category_screen(self.object_list)
        context['count'] = self.object_list.count()

        return context
```

Comment: thank you so much! How do I define self.location? My url stub is: `url(r'local/(?P<location>[-\w]+)/$', views.Courses_By_Location.as_view(),
        name='by_location'),`

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a `dispatch` override -- this will set `self.location`.

Comment: Again thank you so much. My general location is `class Gen_Location(models.Model):
    gen_local = models.CharField('General Location',
                                 max_length=200,)

    display_gen_local = models.CharField('Display Location',
                                         max_length=200,
                                         )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.gen_local` Does this mean I change the `location__name__iexact` to `location__charfield__iexact`? As it's throwing up a Field error

Comment: I've sorted it now, I put in `gen_local`, thank you so much, you should put your answer as a model structure on class based Django ORM. I have been looking all over the internet and this is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the model from models.py?

You should import the model by,

```
from .models import Course
```

Comment: Silly my I forgot the prefix models it's now recognizing it, but now throwing up the error: "Object is of type 'module', but must be a Django Model, Manager, or QuerySet"

Comment: Can you post the trace?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have taken the other answer as he has completely rewritten the view and it works so well and is very clear. Again thank you for taking the time out to help me.